# Assign object values to constant with checking values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am getting features object and assigning to constants according to their values

```
const {
  featureCode,
  featureSubType,
  contentId,
  price,
  family: {
    relationCountsConfig: { motherCount, fatherCount, childrenCount },
    maxFamilyMembersCount
  },
  featureWeight
} = feature;
```

Some time `feature.family` return `{} empty object`.

I am getting mother count undefined error.

**How do we handle when it's assigning to constants.**

Answer (score 0):

```
let feature = {
 featureCode : 'hi',
 featureSubType: 'h',
 contentId: 1,
 price: 1,
 family: {
  relationCountsConfig: { motherCount: 1, fatherCount: 1, childrenCount:1 },
  maxFamilyMembersCount: 10
 },
 featureWeight : 20
}

const {
 featureCode,
 featureSubType,
 contentId,
 price,
 family,
 featureWeight
} = feature;

console.log(family);
```

Try to spread family object later.

Comment: This is not what actually I am looking, assigning the default values to family resolve the issue.